# calculate disk usage percentage to match df Use% output

Tags: rust, linux-disk-free

I am trying to calculate and display in percentage the current disk usage with this:

```
use nix::sys::statvfs::statvfs;

macro_rules! cast {
    ($x:expr) => {
        u64::from($x)
    };
}

fn main() {
    let stat = statvfs("/var/db".as_bytes()).unwrap();
    // f_frsize
    // let total_space = cast!(stat.fragment_size()) * cast!(stat.blocks());
    // let avail_space = cast!(stat.fragment_size()) * cast!(stat.blocks_available());
    // f_bsize
    let total_space = cast!(stat.block_size()) * cast!(stat.blocks());
    let avail_space = cast!(stat.block_size()) * cast!(stat.blocks_available());
    let used = total_space - avail_space;
    let usage = used * 100 / total_space;
    println!("total: {}", total_space);
    println!("avail: {}", avail_space);
    println!("used:  {}", used);
    println!("use%:  {}%", usage);
}
```

The output on my current test system is:

```
total: 6779424768
avail: 3697811456
used:  3081613312
use%:  45%
```

Output of `df -B 1 /var/db`

```
# df -B 1 /var/db
Filesystem      1B-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop3     6779424768 2713636864 3697811456  43% /var/db
```

`Used` field not matching `2713636864` I am calculating it by doing `6779424768-3697811456 = 3081613312`

Output of `df -h /var/db`:

```
# df -h /var/db
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop3      6.4G  2.6G  3.5G  43% /var/db
```

I think I am missing something probably converting the units, I tried already using `f_frsize` instead of `f_bsize` and result still the same, the code above returns `45` and df `43`.

Any ideas?

Comment: probably related: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/829